# How to convert an atomic vector to a class of another vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that coerces an atomic vector to class of another vector, but it doesn't work very well...

```
convertClass <- function(from, to)
{
    # this is really ugly and fails in some cases
    eval(parse(text = paste0("as.", class(to), "(", deparse(dput(from)), ")")))
}

convertClass(c("1", "0"), c(FALSE)) # FAILS, desired output is c(TRUE, FALSE)
convertClass(c("1", "0"), c(1L))
convertClass(c("1", "0"), c(1.5))
convertClass(c("1", "0"), c("XYZ"))
convertClass(c("1", "0"), factor("A"))
```

Any more elegant and actually functional solution?

Comment: 1. Forget `eval(parse())`. Seriously, just forget it. 2. How do you expect R to convert an arbitrary character vector to a logical vector? `as.logical` will fail with your first test case.

Comment: or use `as(from, class(to))`

Comment: Keep the input "from" as numeric? Then it would work for all cases. But why we need this function, maybe there is a different approach to your bigger problem?

Comment: @Roland I don't expect arbitrary input, it should be always 'corvertible'

Comment: I'm trying to 'adjust' the behavior of `plyr::mapvalues`, which seems to convert its result to the class of the `from` argument. E.g. `plyr::mapvalues("A", "A", FALSE, warn_missing = FALSE)` returns `"FALSE"` instead of `FALSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an xy problem, but the following function should work in many cases:

```
convertClass <- function(from, to)
{
  stopifnot(is.atomic(c(unclass(to))))
  if (is.factor(to)) return(factor(from))
  if (inherits(to, "POSIXct")) return(as.POSIXct(from))
  tryCatch(as(from, class(to)), error = function(e) {class(from) <- class(to); from})
}
```

It fails in your first test case but so does `as.logical`.